# Idiom for someone who is in good position/mood

Tags: idiom-requests

What is the idiom for someone who is in a good mood or position? For example, your colleague is in a very good mood because of a recent thing that happened to him.

Comment: What do you mean _good mood or position_? Being in a good mood is fundamentally different from being in a good position—the two are completely unrelated!

Comment: [idioms related to happiness](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/happiness-sadness/happiness-sadness1.html)

Comment: @Noah, by "good position" did you mean specifically good circumstance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A common expression for that emotion is **[on top of the world](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+top+of+the+world)**.

Answer (score 8):

In the UK, you’d often hear the colloquial expression, ‘[chuffed to bits](http://www.effingpot.com/slang.shtml)’ (effingpot.com).

Other options include ‘[in seventh heaven](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Seventh+heaven)’ (thefreedictionary.com), ‘[on cloud nine](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/On+cloud+nine)’ (ditto), ‘as happy as ...’ (Various options [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100828001945AAsOrIs) (answers.yahoo.com), or make up your own), and adjectives such as ‘ecstatic’.

Answer (score 5):

You can say he's in high spirits. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+high+spirits

Answer (score 4):

Someone who's content because they're in a good position as a result of something that [usually, *recently*] happened might well be described as...

> [**sitting pretty**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sitting+pretty) *- in a good situation*

But it's worth noting there's often a suggestion of [*envy*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/envy) in the usage. On reflection, I think the vast majority of expressions that simultaneously allude to someone's current happiness *and* the fact that it was caused by something that [just] happened probably tend to convey some degree of envy (facetiously or not). That's Anglophones for you.

Answer (score 2):

The term *[chipper](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chipper)* would adequately cover this, and is perhaps slightly more formal than some of the (perfectly valid) examples in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

[Elated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elated) is a neutral word that can be used in any English-speaking country.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know why this was worth a downvote rather than an upvote?

Answer (score 1):

You could say he was *[like a pig in shit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/happy_as_a_pig_in_shit)*:-

> (UK and Ireland, slang, simile, vulgar) Extremely happy, visibly happy
>   and carefree.

or perhaps *[happy as Larry](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/as-happy-as-larry.html)*:-

> Very happy.

if you need something slightly more refined.

Answer (score 1):

"Happy as a Clam" is common in the US as well.

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/as-happy-as-a-clam.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also say someone is **[walking on air](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=walking%20on%20air)**, perhaps as a result of being in a good position.

There's also the common US idiom **[high on the hog](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high_on_the_hog)**, which would also be appropriate when speaking about a good position, but does not necessarily relate to mood.

Answer (score 0):

How about "in the catbird seat"? This goes more toward position than mood.